# Gitlab-runner run too long

Tags: gitlab, jekyll, gitlab-ci

I made a static site and now trying to configure GitLab CI/CD.

The source code for the site is on a remote server.

This is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: ruby:2.6


variables:
  JEKYLL_ENV: production

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build --watch 

  only:
    - master
```

I use `--watch` because without using --watch job passed correctly, changes are displayed on the local computer, but no updates are displayed on the remote server.

There is a line in the answer:

`Auto-regeneration: disabled for '/ builds / wiki / docplus'. Use --watch to enable`

But with `--watch` I push my commits and gitlab-runner runs too long and job failed

```
$ bundle exec jekyll build --watch
Configuration file: /builds/wiki/docplus/_config.yml
            Source: /builds/wiki/docplus
       Destination: /builds/wiki/docplus/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 1.863 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/builds/wiki/docplus'
Pulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-003fe500 ...
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

What's wrong?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/6697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `deploy.script` to just `build` (without `--watch`):

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build
```

Comment: I tried it, job is passed, but...
Without flag "--watch" auto-regeneration is disabled, and all updates are not displayed on the site.

Comment: You use `--watch` when running `jekyll build` **on your local computer**. When you use CI/CD to deploy your site, a new job is triggered by every push to the repository. Also, when developing the site on a local machine, you can run `jekyll serve` (which includes `--watch` by default) and point your browser to `http://localhost:4000`.

Comment: Updated description of my problem

Comment: the problem is not with **local computer** the problem is with updates on a **remote server**

Comment: Looks like you don't understand the problem correctly. Let me try and explain. GitLab Runner runs a job on every push to the repo. The runner deems the job to have completed based on the exit status sent by the process within a predefined amount of time. Now, when you run `jekyll build --watch`, the process never sends an exit status (because it is meant to *watch the repo for changes* till you manually kill the process).

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. But what needs to be done so that updates are displayed on the remote server. Now I think, that the problem is not in gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Please read through the documentation regarding deploying via Gitlab Pages: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started/new_or_existing_website.html and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_four.html